# MKMapView Add Overlay outside of a radius

Tags: ios, mkmapview

If I want to add overlay color to MKMapView inside a certain radius it's easily done with MKCircleView. But how can I add the overlay **outside** of a specified radius,  like the Reminders app does, as the above image?

[image: Reminders]

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428918/how-overlay-a-circle-on-an-ios-map